# c++ makefile not finding shared library for hdf5

Tags: c++, makefile, installation, shared-libraries, ubuntu

I'm compiling a c++ program on Kubuntu that will use the hdf5 library. I have installed the hdf5 library using

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-7
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-cpp-7
```

But when I run the makefile for the program I get

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/local/lib/libhdf5.so', needed by 'src/libHDF5Wrapper.so'.  Stop.
```

And indeed looking in `/usr/lib` there is no `libhdf5*`-files. Am I missing something in the installation of hdf5?

Comment: if I run `ldconfig -p | grep libhdf5.so` I get `libhdf5.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so`, so I guess your makefile wrongly assumes that this library is at `/usr/local/lib`. Post the makefile to see where this assumption is made.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I have the same path; I changed it and now it works. However now it can't find the header `H5Cpp.h`. Looking at the Ubuntu webpages this should be included in `libhdf5-serial-dev`, which I have installed, and located at `/usr/include/`, but when I look it's not there, although some other hdf5 headers are. Any ideas?

Comment: you need `libhdf5-dev`: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libhdf5-dev/filelist

Comment: It worked, thanks! I had installed that earlier but turned out it had been removed when I installed some other libraries in confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to close this question I put my comment into this answer:

The correct location of the libraries on Ubuntu can either be found out using the [online file list of the respective package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libhdf5-7/filelist) or through:

```
ldconfig -p | grep libhdf5.so
```

which for me returns:

```
libhdf5.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so
```

Your makefile seems to wrongly assume the location of the library to be `/usr/local/lib`, so you need to adjust the makefile to match the actual install location on your computer.